# How to reset BAT file association in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, file-association

I've seen several answers for earlier versions of windows, but not 10 -- I'm runnning Windows 10.0.17134, if that matters.

It's currently set so that, on double-clicking a BAT file, it opens in Notepad++, so it's clearly something I did inadvertently (probably trying to set a program for editing, as opposed to opening). I've looked in "Settings / Choose default apps by file type" and see that BAT and CMD are both set for Notepad++, but I don't know how to reset it. If I click on the current setting, it allows me to choose Notepad++ (again, I guess) or "find an app in the app store"; after a LONG time searching (I guess) it says there are no results for ".bat". There's nothing about restoring the default.

How can I get this done?

Comment: This "duplicate" is for windows 8 -- I'm nervous about messing with the registry this way for a different version of Windows, is there anyone who has done this for Windows 10?

Comment: This is absolutely a duplicate.  The solution to this problem is not Windows version specific.  If anything the duplicate should be tagged as a general Windows question.

Comment: You may use the BAT file association registry fix from here [File Association Fixes for Windows 10](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-association-fixes-windows-10/)